# Can I have multiple bean interconnection versions with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Spring configuration file creates beans and interconnects them. Is this correct? I have a chain of beans in my application but want to test it with smaller chains. Can I have multiple chains defined with Spring? Or only one bean structure is allowed?

**EXAMPLE**

Suppose this is production config:

```
<bean id="provider"
    class="tests.Provider">
</bean>

<bean id="processor1" class="tests.Processor1">
    <property name="input" ref="provider"/>
</bean>

<bean id="processor2" class="tests.Processor2">
    <property name="input" ref="processor1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="consumer" class="tests.Consumer">
    <property name="input" ref="processor2"/>
</bean>
```

And I want to test in the following configs:

```
<bean id="provider"
    class="tests.Provider">
</bean>

<bean id="analyzer" class="tests.Analyzer">
    <property name="input" ref="provider"/>
</bean>
```

And:

```
<bean id="provider"
    class="tests.Provider">
</bean>

<bean id="processor1" class="tests.Processor1">
    <property name="input" ref="provider"/>
</bean>

<bean id="analyzer" class="tests.Analyzer">
    <property name="input" ref="processor1"/>
</bean>
```

And so on, attaching beans one by one.

Comment: could you give the example of the structure you are talking about

Comment: Can you provide an example? What's a "bean chain"? You can define whatever you want, just give them different IDs/names. Or use different config files for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can break overall configuration of Spring application context for your application into parts (XML files if you use XML configuration, packages with `@Components` if you use classpath scanning, `@Configuration`s if you use Java-based configuration) and construct an application context using a subset of these parts.

So, if your application has two features `foo` and `bar`, you can declare beans used by these features in `foo.xml` and `bar.xml` respectively (if you use XML configuration), and import them from the main configuration of your application (such as `applicationContext.xml`).

Now, if you want to write integration test for `bar` you can create application context from `bar.xml` only (`@ContextConfiguration("bar.xml")`). Obviously, you should take care of interdependencies between different parts of your configuration. For example, if both `foo.xml` and `bar.xml` depend on beans declared in `db.xml`, you may want to create something like `test-db.xml` and configure your integration test for `bar` as `@ContextConfiguration({"bar.xml", "test-db.xml"})`.

Note that this approach requres some discipline, especially if you use classpath scanning - in this case parts of your configuration are defined by packages, therefore you need to  follow "package by feature, not by layer" rule.

**See also:**

- [9.3 Integration testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to test for integration, what I usually do is to separate my bean configuration files in  tiers and then import them as needed for testing. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:mx/gob/jgtjo/apps/schedule/web/schedule-web.properties"
        file-encoding="UTF-8" system-properties-mode="NEVER" />

    <!-- Context files -->
    <import resource="spring/dataContext.xml" />
    <import resource="spring/serviceContext.xml" />
    <import resource="spring/securityContext.xml" />
    <import resource="spring/components.xml" />

</beans>
```

And then, if I need to test for Daos, I only import the dataContext.xml inside a testContextDao.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms spring framework takes care of Object Creation. These objects you want Spring to manage you define them as beans. So when spring creates a bean1 if that bean1 has reference to bean2, the bean2 is instantiated and injected to bean1 and finally bean1 is created. Thinking of it as chain will be over complicating.

[Section 3.2 of spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html)